# ARM: Using bit-banded memory from C or C++

Tags: c, compilation, embedded, bit-manipulation, cortex-m

ARM Cortex supports bit-banded memory, where individual bits are mapped to "bytes" in certain regions.  I believe that only certain parts of RAM are bit-banded.  I'd like to use bit-banding from C and C++.

How do I this? It seems I'd need to:

1. Tell the compiler to place certain variables in bit-banded regions.  How? What if the variables are elements of a `struct`?
2. Tell the compiler, when I want to access a bit, to turn `if (flags & 0x4)` into `if (flags_bb_04)`.  Ideally, I'd like this to be automatic, and to fall back to the former if bit banding isn't available.

Comment: Only some ARM Cortex supports bit-banding, it was optional and the option is removed from later models because no one found anything very useful to do with it.  Apart from your own interest/entertainment, what problem do you think that this is going to solve that can't be done more easily using conventional methods?

Comment: Bit-banding can ensure single bit writes are atomic; otherwise, you can get inconsistent vals if two writes clobber each other.  I also imagine `flag4 = 1` is faster than `flag |= 0x8` since it replaces a read, arithmetic, write, with a single write.

Comment: Bit banding is implemented as a read-modify-write cycle on the whole word.  It is atomic from the processor's point of view (just as if you turned interrupts off) but I'm not sure that it is guaranteed to be atomic from the point of view of other bus users such as DMA.  It also cannot make the memory go any faster than it is.  If you do 10 bit banding writes that still requires 10 reads and 10 writes of the target memory.  This is certainly slower than one read, 10 modifications and one write, if you are accessing the bits in the same word consecutively.

Comment: of course you can use it from C since you can read-write whatever address you write.  but you certainly would never want to point structures across compile domains (at hardware registers) and you would definitely never want to use bitfields, so there is you useful C/C++ benefits there.   The point of this feature was essentially to do an atomic read-modify-write of control registers like change one output pin on a gpio port (where the chip vendor has not provided that directly through another register).

Comment: Bit and bits are mapped to 32bit _words_ not "bytes".

Comment: @TomV I have to disagree that it is not useful, I have used it extensively.  It does however result in code that is hard to test off the target or to port, so should be used advisedly perhaps. The real reason it was not supported in M7 I believe is because it would make the DCACHE implementation rather complex perhaps.

Comment: @Clifford: Perhaps I meant I can't think of anything to do with it that has an advantage which outweighs the increased complexity.  Did you use it for performance reasons or to make synchronization easier?  Would you care to give details if I ask this as a new question?

Comment: @TomV I gave one example in ithe answer to this question.  Atomically enabling/disabling peripheral interrupt enable bits, bitbanging GPIO to implement a soft-UART are examples I have used. More niche perhaps I have used it to assemble data frames for a communication protocol that has variable bit-width fields that do not conveniently align to byte boundaries (ITU-R M.1371 if it is of interest) it made the code simpler, but lack of portability dissuaded me from continuing to do that - so you have a point perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use regular variables and access them through thier bit-band address. For that you do not need to "tell the compiler" anything. For example, given:

```
extern "C" volatile uint32_t* getBitBandAddress( volatile const void* address, int bit )
{
    volatile uint32_t* bit_address = 0;
    uint32_t addr = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>(address);

    // This bit maniplation makes the function valid for RAM
    // and Peripheral bitband regions
    uint32_t word_band_base = addr & 0xf0000000;
    uint32_t bit_band_base = word_band_base | 0x02000000;
    uint32_t offset = addr - word_band_base;

    // Calculate bit band address
    bit_address = reinterpret_cast<volatile uint32_t*>(bit_band_base + (offset * 32u) + (static_cast<uint32_t>(bit) * 4u));

    return bit_address ;
}
```

you could create a 32bit "array" thus:

```
uint32_t word = 0 ;
uint32_t* bits = getBitbandAddress( word, 0 ) ;

bits[5] = 1 ; // word now == 32 (bit 5 set).
```

Now if you have a part with external or CCM memory for example that is not bitbandable, you do need to ensure that the *linker* ( not the compiler) places the normal memory object in bitbandable memory.  How that is done is toolchain specific but in gnu for example you might have:

```
uint32_t word __attribute__ ((section ("ISRAM1"))) = 0 ;
```

Bitbanding is perhaps most useful for atomically accessing individual bits in peripheral registers. For fast and thread-safe access.

Some compilers are bitband aware and may automatically optimise *single bit* bitfield access using bitbanding.  So for example;

```
struct
{
    bit1 : 1 ;
    bit2 : 1 ;
} bits __attribute__ ((section ("BITBANDABLE")));
```

The compiler (at least armcc v5) may optimise this to utilise the bitband access to `bits.bit1` and `bits.bit2`.  YMMV.